# Algorithm to generate a user unique, 6-character confirmation code?

Tags: encoding, hash, uniqueidentifier

I'd like to be able to create an algorithm that generates a 6 character confirmation code (e.g. A1JU2Z) that will be unique for a given (user, code) pair.  The reason is, I'd like to keep the code at 6 characters, but using a trimmed set of alphanumerics (to avoid confusion with 1 and I, etc) only allows for ~300 million codes before collisions occur.  Sure I may never need 300 million codes, but if I do, it will be a huge pain to go back and fix this.

So is there a way to utilize the user ... say their username, to generic unique codes such that if the same user wants to generate another code, its guaranteed that it is unique for them?  (This is of course assuming a single user doesn't generate over 300 mill codes)

Thanks!

Comment: Where does _code_ in the `(user, code)` pair come from?

Comment: @Attila - I may be wording this poorly, but basically I want to be able to generate codes using the user's username (for example) + some other sequence.  So globally unique pairs of (username, confirmation code).

Comment: I think user name + confirmation code will always be over 6 chars.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that if you generate an ID that is unique to a _given user_ (but not necessarily _between users_), then (user, ID) will already be guaranteed to be unique globally.  Or do you want the ID to be globally unique while incorporating the user's ID as well?

Comment: @Attila - I want to be able to generate multiple IDs for a given user that do not need to be unique globally, but must be unique for that user.  I'd like to be able to do this mathematically to avoid DB lookups (although it's sounding like that may be inevitable).

Answer (score 1):

If the ID is unique only to the current user, you can just generate each character of the ID randomly.  As long as the user is not expected to generate a large number of such IDs, you will have reasonable chance of not generating the same ID more than once (you need to do some math to get exact numbers for the expected chance of collision as the number of generated ID grow).

If you *must not* have collision at all cost, you need to either keep all previously generated IDs and do a comparison for the new one, or keep the count of the generated IDs (this requires a scheme where the ID generation is deterministic based on the count, but also unique -- a very simple case would be `{ID=count; ++count;}`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a simple password generator like this : http://www.webtoolkit.info/php-random-password-generator.html

in combination with a check algorithm to be sure it is not already used.

```
$pass=generate_password();
$found=find_password($pass);
while($found){
    $pass=generate_password();
    $found=find_password($pass);
}
save_password($user,$code,$pass);
```

generate_password() is the function refered in the link.
find_password() is a function you have to write to check already generated codes in a database.
save_password() is a function you have to write to store the generated code in a database.

The code is in PHP, but the logic is here.
The password generator in the link is easy to understand, you can get 6 chars long, with the character rules you want.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to avoid the "be sure it is not already used" step.  Basically I want an algorithmic/mathematical way to generate a unique code for a user as a function of that user's username.

Comment: So you are searching for a Hash algorithm (md5, sha1). With 6 chars, the collision risk is big. The easiest way to me is to get 6 chars from md5 or other hash algorithm result.